# AS3, variables outside event handler function?

Tags: actionscript-3, function, flash, variables

I have searched arond, but cant seem to find a proper answer to this. Lets say we have a super basic program which adds two numbers from 2 input text fields togehter and prints them out. Why cant i accses variables outside the event handler function? And what do i have to do in order to achieve this? The code is on a frame.

Why does this example not work? :

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cal);

var fnum:Number = Number(txt1.text);
var snum:Number = Number(txt2.text);

function cal(evt:MouseEvent){


txtOutput.text = String(fnum + snum);
}
```

And this example work?:

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cal);

function cal(evt:MouseEvent){

var fnum:Number = Number(txt1.text);
var snum:Number = Number(txt2.text);
txtOutput.text = String(fnum + snum);
}
```

Comment: Is this from a class or on a frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to be this guy, but I can't get it to replicate whats happening for you..

[image]

The only assumption that I can make is that the txt1.text & txt2.text aren't set yet when the button is clicked in example 1. Feel free to zip your project and dropbox it to me if you want me to investigate further :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its not really a project, i just created the  code to illustrate my problem. If i set the variables values manually in the code as you did, it works fine. But im pretty sure that, as you said, txt1.text and txt2.text aren't set when the button is clicked! How do i set them, is there a method for this? ?@Zze

Comment: AS3 is compiled top to bottom.
If you look at my image, the events are assigned, then the numbers.
In your case, fnum & snum are set to the text element of your input fields. 
Therefore if these fields are blank at this time then your vars will be blank.
Put a trace statement in before you assign them to test this.
I garuntee that if you add some text into these fields on the stage this will work.
Its simply the fact that no data has been entered into the fields at the time the variables have been set.